# How do display and iterate through haystack result objects using solr

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am a couple of days into django-haystack using Solr backend and I am thoroughly confused by it. I tried this

```
def search_title(request):
  posts = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=request.GET.get('search_text', ''))
  context = {
    "posts": posts
  }
  # context.update(csrf(request))
  return render(request, "posts/ajax_search.html", context)
```

and I would get these error messages in my terminal

```
Model could not be found for SearchResult '<SearchResult: posts.post (pk='10')>'.
Model could not be found for SearchResult '<SearchResult: posts.post (pk='10')>'.
```

One entry would return double results. So, to see if I could display something in the template I had this in my views.py

```
all_results = SearchQuerySet().all()
context = {
    "all_results": all_results
```

and in my list_view.html I had

```
{{ all_results }}
```

and it returned the following

```
<SearchResult: posts.post (pk='2')>,
<SearchResult: posts.post (pk='3')>, 
<SearchResult: posts.post (pk='4')>,
<SearchResult: posts.post (pk='5')>,
```

so I then tried to iterate through it like this

```
{% for a in all_results %}
   {{a.object.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

and nothing is returned. What is the proper way to get the results and iterate through them?

Comment: any update dear i am facing same problem